# What is the Postgres equivalent of SQL Server's If Exists(

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a T-SQL query I would like to be able to use in Postgres. I'm new to Postgres and would like to know if the `If Exists` is possible as well as the `Print` or what the equivalents would be.

Basically it is just checking to see if there is any info in a table and if there is then it calls a stored procedure, if not it posts nothing to report in the logs, that part isn't really needed but I would like to know the print if possible.

```
IF Exists(Select * from [mytable]
Having Count(*) > 0)

EXEC sp_someprocedure
ELSE
PRINT 'Table Empty: Nothing to report.'
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure does, for example:

```
do $$begin
if exists (select * from yourtable) then
    perform your_function();
else
    raise notice 'nothing to report';
end if;
end$$;
```